# Can't create correct formula to draw line chart with rules in vega-lite?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Working on project with vega-lite and can't overcome with some visualization. Stuck on this task

I would like to get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1edfC.png)  , but getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g12WH.png).

This is my code I tried:
`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  

  "params": [
    {
      "name": "chart_title",
      "value": " Weekly  Distribution"
    },
    {
      "name": "titleAxisXname",
      "value": "Weekly  Min "
    },
    {
      "name": "tick_Count_X",
      "value": 8
    }
    
  ],
  "width": 425,
  "height": 135,
  "padding": 20,
  "title": {
    "text": {
      "expr": "chart_title"
    },
    "fontSize": 16,
    "color": "white",
    "fontWeight": 700,
    "font": "Google Sans",
    "align": "left",
    "dx": 40,
    "dy": -10
  },
  
  
  "data": {
    "name": "vis",
    "values":[
      {
  "customer": "Customer",
  "type": "monthly",
  "metrics": {
    
    "partitions": [
      {
        "a": {
          "mean": 135,
          "distribution": {
            "min": [ 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,300],
            
            "data": [
              0.01,
              0.01,
              0.02,
              0.03,
              0.05,
              0.08,
              0.13,
              0.21,
              0.28,
              0.31,
              0.33,
              0.3,
              0.28,
              0.26,
              0.24,
              0.22,
              0.21,
              0.2,
              0.19,
              0.18,
              0.17,
              0.16,
              0.15,
              0.14,
              0.13,
              0.12,
              0.11,
              0.1,
              0.09,
              0.08
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
   
  }
    }]
  },
  "transform": [
  
    {"calculate": "datum.metrics.partitions", "as": "P"},
    {"flatten": ["P"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.P.a.distribution.min", "as": "x"},
    {"flatten": ["x"]},
   
   {"calculate": "datum.P.a.distribution.data", "as": "y"},
    {"flatten": ["y"]}
    
   ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": { "field": "x", 
        "type": "quantitative"
        },
        
        "y": { 
          "field": "y",
          "type": "quantitative"
          
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {}
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 65
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "25th",
              "Percentile"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 130
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule",
            "color": "#594CB8"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "50th",
              "Percentile"
            ],
            "color": "#594CB8"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 200
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule",
            "color": "#B4539E"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "75th",
              "Percentile"
            ],
            "color": "#B4539E"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  
  "config": {
    "background": "white",
    "axisX": {
      "title": {
        "expr": "titleAxisXname"
      },
      "tickCount": {
        "expr": "tick_Count_X"
      },
      "titlePadding": 20,
      "titleFont": "Google Sans",
      "titleColor": "black",
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontWeight": 700,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400
    },
    "axisY": {
      "orient": "right",
      "tickCount": 3,
      "format": "%",
      "title": null,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400,
      "labelPadding": 10
    },
    "line": {
      "point": false,
      "interpolate": "cardinal",
      "color": "#006A62"
    },
    "text": {
      "font": "Google Sans",
      "fontSize": 12,
      "color": "#001D33",
      "fontWeight": 700,
      "dx": 15,
      "dy": -105
    },
    "rule": {
      "strokeWidth": 5,
      "strokeDash": [
        0.5,
        16
      ],
      "strokeCap": "round"
    }
  }
}
```

`

Can't come up with correct calculations which reads x and y fields.
It should be way but I can't find in documentations

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your flatten created a Cartesian product and needed to be done in a single step.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  

  "params": [
    {
      "name": "chart_title",
      "value": " Weekly A Distribution"
    },
    {
      "name": "titleAxisXname",
      "value": "Weekly A Minutes "
    },
    {
      "name": "tick_Count_X",
      "value": 8
    }
    
  ],
  "width": 425,
  "height": 135,
  "padding": 20,
  "title": {
    "text": {
      "expr": "chart_title"
    },
    "fontSize": 16,
    "color": "#56615F",
    "fontWeight": 700,
    "font": "Google Sans",
    "align": "right",
    "dx": 40,
    "dy": -10
  },
  
  
  "data": {
    "name": "report",
    "values":[
      {
  "customer": "Customer",
  "type": "monthly",
  "period": "2022-10",
  "schema": "1.0.0",
  "metrics": {
    "filters": {
      "age": [
        "all",
        "18-39",
        "40-64",
        "65+"
      ],
      "gender": [
        "all",
        "male",
        "female"
      ]
    },
    "partitions": [
      {
        "segment": {
          "age": "*",
          "gender": "*"
        },
        "count": 10000,
        "a": {
          "mean": 135,
          "p10": 10,
          "p25": 60,
          "p50": 130,
          "p75": 198,
          "p90": 255,
          "goal": {
            "value": 150,
            "p": 0.37
          },
          "distribution": {
            "min": [ 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250,260,270,280,300],
            "max": 300,
            "step": 10,
            "data": [
              0.01,
              0.01,
              0.02,
              0.03,
              0.05,
              0.08,
              0.13,
              0.21,
              0.28,
              0.31,
              0.33,
              0.3,
              0.28,
              0.26,
              0.24,
              0.22,
              0.21,
              0.2,
              0.19,
              0.18,
              0.17,
              0.16,
              0.15,
              0.14,
              0.13,
              0.12,
              0.11,
              0.1,
              0.09,
              0.08
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
   
  }
    }]
  },
  "transform": [
  
    {"calculate": "datum.metrics.partitions", "as": "P"},
    {"flatten": ["P"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.P.a.distribution.min", "as": "x"},
  
   
   {"calculate": "datum.P.a.distribution.data", "as": "y"},
    {"flatten": ["x","y"]}
    
   ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": { "field": "x", 
        "type": "quantitative"
        },
        
        "y": { 
          "field": "y",
          "type": "quantitative"
          
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {}
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 65
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "25th",
              "Percentile"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 130
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule",
            "color": "#594CB8"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "50th",
              "Percentile"
            ],
            "color": "#594CB8"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 200
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule",
            "color": "#B4539E"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "75th",
              "Percentile"
            ],
            "color": "#B4539E"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  
  "config": {
    "background": "#eff1ef",
    "axisX": {
      "title": {
        "expr": "titleAxisXname"
      },
      "tickCount": {
        "expr": "tick_Count_X"
      },
      "titlePadding": 20,
      "titleFont": "Google Sans",
      "titleColor": "#56615F",
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontWeight": 700,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400
    },
    "axisY": {
      "orient": "right",
      "tickCount": 3,
      "format": "%",
      "title": null,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400,
      "labelPadding": 10
    },
    "line": {
      "point": false,
      "interpolate": "cardinal",
      "color": "#006A62"
    },
    "text": {
      "font": "Google Sans",
      "fontSize": 12,
      "color": "#001D33",
      "fontWeight": 700,
      "dx": 15,
      "dy": -105
    },
    "rule": {
      "strokeWidth": 5,
      "strokeDash": [
        0.5,
        16
      ],
      "strokeCap": "round"
    }
  }
}
```